# Share function implementation between two files in C

Tags: c

I want to share some function implementation between couple of files.
To be more specific, I want **file1.c**  and **file2.c** to both be able to use the same function (instead of just the copy-paste solution), call it **func()**.
So what I have is:

file1:

```
#include"shared.h"
int main() {
    int x=func();
}
```

file2:

```
#include"shared.h"
int main() {
    int y=func();
}
```

shared.h:

```
extern int func();
```

shared.c:

```
#include"Shared.h"
int func() {
    // some implementation here
}
```

When I try to compile it with `gcc file1.c` I get "undefined reference to 'func()'"...
How do I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile object files, then link them, only the linker will check the references:

```
gcc shared.c -c
gcc file1.c -c
gcc file2.c -c
gcc file1.o shared.o -o program1
gcc file2.o shared.o -o program2
```

Answer (score 2):

The Gcc Linker is looking for an implementation of func(). You can specify multiple *.c files as input for gcc and the linker will search through the generated object files for func().

```
gcc file1.c shared.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile shared.c as well